# Display images like logo in .php file with html img tag

Tags: php, html, image

I am very new to PHP where the same issue have been facing. Coding a simple welcome php page with a logo in png or jpg format does not show in both development and production server.

Tried using changing the permissions to the folders and files but nothing results.

Any idea?

Comment: can you show us your html file? so that we can get an idea where is the issue.

Comment: Can you check if any error in the Network panel of the developer tool? e.g. image is not loading, wrong path etc.

Comment: @WisdmLabs You are right, I get the error message - "Could not load the image"

Comment: URL:http://rsbgroups.co.in/rsbgroups.co.in/logo_rsbgroups.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0

Comment: Host:rsbgroups.co.in
Referer:http://rsbgroups.co.in/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sun, 01 Mar 2015 06:11:20 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.36

Comment: Finally could find the error in .htaccess
removed RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php

Answer (score 0):

to do this, you could simply include a PHP echo code segment in your HTML file. for instance,

```
<html>
     <div id="banner">
         <?php echo '<image src="logo.jpg" />'; ?>
     </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried all these stuff, even tried fetching with code. Get a massage - "Could not load the image"

Comment: Do I need to mention in .htaccess?

Answer (score -1):

I've used this code to display my logo:

```
echo "<img src="https://yangtzesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/logo-150x150.png" <?php imageResize(100,100, 150); ?>>";
```

It will display image from the source URL: https://yangtzesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/logo-150x150.png

Comment: another person has answered a similar thing before and the asker said that it doesnt work

Comment: hmmmm I think you might need to change the outer double quotes to single ones or use the escape chars on the inner ones.
`'<img src="https://yangtzesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/logo-150x150.png" >';`
or
`"<img src=\"https://yangtzesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/logo-150x150.png\" >";`